# Get generic object from hibernate query

Tags: java, generics, jpa

As described in http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/ultimate-jpa-queries-and-tips-list-part_7092.html, you can get objects from a jpa query.
So far, so good.

But since I will have to use this quite often, I want to use generics.
So instead of

```
Query query = em.createQuery('select new com.model.PersonDogAmountReport(p, size(p.dogs)) from Person p');
```

I want

```
Query query = em.createQuery('select new com.model.Report<Person, Long>(p, size(p.dogs)) from Person p');
```

or

```
Query query = em.createQuery('select new com.model.Report<com.model.Person, java.lang.Long>(p, size(p.dogs)) from Person p');
```

. Trying this gives me the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found '<' near line 1
```

Does this mean, that what I want is just not supported?
Are there good alternatives?

Nearly the same thing is possible with *NamedNativeQuery* and *resultClass*, but that way I wouldn't get Person as an entity.

If I use object instead, the returned List cannot be cast, meaning I have to iterate -> meh desu.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating instances of Reports like this is not safe anyway, since Hibernate uses reflection to instantiate and populate the reports. So you could simply do:

```
Query query = em.createQuery('select new com.model.Report(p, size(p.dogs)) from Person p');
return (List<Report<Person, Long>>) query.list();
```

Comment: Wow, this works, although I thought it shouldn't. Thanks a lot.
Care to explain why this works?

Comment: The explanation is in @JohnB's answer. A `Report<Person, Long>`, at runtime, is in fact a `Report<Object, Object>`. It can hold anything. It's only the compiler that makes a generic type safe.

Comment: Follow up question: Using this approach instead of Tom Andersons, Eclipse shows me "No constructors can be found that match the argument types." It works, but the red mark is a hassle. Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: Follow up note: Newer versions of eclipse, understand the syntax and do not show that error anymore.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to remember here is that with Java generics type-erasure will remove all generic types. This will reduce a `List<Person>` to simply a `List<Object>` with the appropriate casts. At runtime there is no such thing as a `List<Person>`. So in a situation like this, just get a `List` and do the casts yourself.

Comment: Well, thanks for the explanation. Now I know what to google for.

Answer (score 2):

A thing you might consider is using a trivial subclass to bind the generic types. So:

```
package com.model;

public class PersonLongReport extends Report<Person, Long> {
    public PersonLongReport(Person person, Long long) {
        super(person, long);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
public List<? extends Report<Person, Long>> doQuery() {
    TypedQuery<PersonLongReport> query = em.createQuery('select new com.model.PersonLongReport(p, size(p.dogs)) from Person p', PersonLongReport.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

For the cost of that trivial subclass, you get type safety.